# Where did I opt-in to special job offers?

Tags: support, email, stack-overflow-jobs

In a mail I received from you it stated:

> You're receiving this message because you are opted in to Stack Overflow emails about special jobs.

I am wondering when and where I am supposed to have done that?
Is there any way to get that information?

I know where i can edit my mail settings.

But since it is explicitly denoted as me being opted in, meaning i opted i.e. chose an option, i want to know where i did that. Or you guys should change your wording on this one and simply state that those emails were enabled without any consent.

Comment: No, an opt in means it is deactivated by default. The term of opting in describes the act of choosing to be in. "Opted in" means that somewhere in the past i must have decided to opt in. Which is why i opened up this question.

Answer (score 5):

You can manage this in your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current). Scroll down to the 'STACK OVERFLOW' section; there you can change if you want to receive emails about recommended jobs.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer *where* you signed up for these. I can't remember where I did, too long ago ...

Comment: You didn't sign-up for those. The feature comes with as default *On* ...

Comment: I got the same email about a job, but I still go to school... I guess if it wasn't on by default, no one would know it was there to enable?

Comment: As stated above it talks about being opted in. Since that word is being used, probably because it sounds soothing to the susceptible ear, i want to know where the act of opting in happened, not how to change my mail settings. What i would be interested in though would be a setting where i could opt out from being "opted in" automatically in general.